# Swift beginner needs elaboration on syntax - Passing and Returning Functions

Tags: swift, function, parameters

I'm venturing into Swift and languages that differ in syntax that I'm used to. The learning curve. I was wondering if someone could help explain this to me.

I understand the following. I understand that the method returns multiple values in a tuple.

---

```
func getGasPrices() -> (Double, Double, Double) {
return (3.59, 3.69, 3.79)
}
```

I don't understand this though. Is **makeIncrementer** returning an Int? Is it returning a returned Int? What's being passed into the **addOne** method and how? If addOne is only returning a single value, then how is makeIncrementer able to return two values? Further, how can the var **increment** (assigned as the makeIncrementer method) be made to take values when the function does not? I'm also not sure how this can be referred to as passing and returning a function, when no function is passed (isn't it nested?)

---

```
// Passing and returning functions
func makeIncrementer() -> (Int -> Int) {
    func addOne(number: Int) -> Int {
        return 1 + number
    }
    return addOne
}
var increment = makeIncrementer()
increment(7)
```

If this question has been answered already, forgive me, I couldn't find it! I'm a beginner in C# and Java so this syntax is completely strange to me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makeIncrementer`is returning a value that is a function. So what is returned is a function that takes a single Integer parameter.

```
func addOne(number: Int) -> Int
```

This function takes an integer and returns another. Swift uses the syntax `(Int -> Int)` to represent this. This is different that returning an integer directly, you may also see instances of functions that take functions as parameters. This may look like the following:

```
func doSomething(completion: ()->())
```